# What are the alternatives to global variables in a Rails multi-tenant application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, multi-tenant

I'm transforming my application (single client) in to a multi-tenant application.

I used to store a few settings (rarely changed / very frequently accessed) into a global variable (a hash).
The values for this global variable were pulled out of the DB when the application started.
Obviously, these settings are specific to a client / tenant.

I now see a few options, but none of them seems good:

- keep the global hash, but introduce the notion of tenant `$global[:client1][:settingX]` but this doesn't feel good/scalable/safe
- Call the DB everytime, but I fear to take a performance hit (~40 additional calls to the DB )

Is there anything I could do with Memcache? But I don't know where to start with option.

Note: the application is hosted on Heroku

Comment: Why would it be 40 DB calls?

Comment: in this typical example: because I need to perform 40 currency conversions. So some of them may be cached if the same currency is used twice, but I cannot rely on this assumption.
I could maybe load all necessary exchange rates once and for all, but that wouldn't be practical at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a great argument for using memcached or redis.  You want a centralized place where these values can live that's accessible to all of your pool of app servers.  Your use case is predominantly read with occasional write to update values.

I would build a currency helper that lazy-loads from memcached/redis once per request and then saves the currency rate data for any value calculations in that request.

I don't know your problem domain, but let's assume you're trying to provide local currency pricing to different users in your system and that the rates are different for different users (ie: discounting, etc).

```
class CurrencyHelper
  attr_reader :currency_rates

  def initialize(user_id)
     @currency_rates = load_or_generate_exchange_rates
  end

  def load_or_generate_exchange_rates
    key = "/currency/rates/#{user_id}"
    REDIS.get(key) || begin
      rates = generate_exchange_rates
      REDIS.put(key, rates)
      rates
    end
  end

  def convert_from_usd_to(amount_usd, currency)
    round_money( usd * currency_rates[currency] )
  end
end
```

In your controller code:

```
  def currency_helper
    @currency_helper ||= CurrencyHelper.new(current_user.id)
  end

  def show
    localized_price = currency_helper.convert_from_usd_to(price_usd, params[:country_code])
  end
```